# stable match algorithm for different sizes groups and limited places

Tags: python, algorithm, stable-marriage

I want to write a program that oriented student to their specialty in university depending on their choices and their range in the specialty.

each specialty can take multiple student (in this case cnm =1 , dsi=2 , rss=2),and the number of student can be more than the number of places (in this case one student not gonna have a place because there is only 5 places ).

The program run with out a problem but the output is not correct .(and I couldn’t know why )
.
The output for this example should be ((a,cnm),(c,rss),(b,dsi),(e,dsi),(f,rss))

i found a video on youtube (https://youtu.be/FhRf0j068ZA ,the source code https://github.com/Schachte/stable-matching-algorithm) where the person explain and write a code for stable matching problem , i liked that code so i toke it and i tried to edited so it can be solve my problem

If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it.

*****this is my code

```
students = {
'A': ['CNM', 'DSI', 'RSS'],
'B': ['CNM', 'DSI', 'RSS'],
'C': ['DSI', 'CNM', 'RSS'],
'D': ['DSI', 'RSS', 'CNM'],
'E': ['RSS', 'DSI', 'CNM'],
'F': ['RSS', 'CNM', 'DSI']
    }

choices = {
   'DSI': ['C', 'E','D', 'B','F','A'],
   'RSS': ['B','F','A', 'E', 'D','C'],
   'CNM': ['A', 'B','C', 'D','E','F']
   }

rss=2
cnm = 1
dsi=2
results = []
students_with_out_choice =[]

for student in students:
     students_with_out_choice.append(student)

while (len(students_with_out_choice) > 0 ):
      for i in range (3):
          for student in students_with_out_choice:
              for choice in students[student]:
                    if ((choice == "DSI" and dsi != 0) or (choice == "RSS" and rss != 0) or (choice == "CNM" and cnm != 0)):
                       results.append([student, choice])
                       students_with_out_choice.remove(student)
                       if (choice == "DSI"):
                          dsi -= 1
                       if (choice == "RSS"):
                          rss -= 1
                       if (choice == "CNM"):
                          cnm -= 1
                       break

                    else:
                       for key, value in results:
                          if choice == value:
                             a= key

                       etudiant_actuel = choices[choice].index(a)
                       etudiant_proposer = choices[choice].index(student)

                       if (etudiant_actuel >etudiant_proposer):
                           students_with_out_choice.remove(student)

                           students_with_out_choice.append(a)

                           a = student
                           break
                       elif(i==2):
                            students_with_out_choice.remove(student)
                            break

print(results)
```

Comment: you should use Deferred Acceptance algorithm. Because in each step, only a tentative matching is stored, when a high priority student comes along later, a school can always match with that student, which assures stability.

Comment: Why is your expected output `((a,cnm),(c,rss),(b,dsi),(e,dsi),(f,rss))`, shouldn't it be `((a,cnm),(c,dsi),(b,rss),(e,dsi),(f,rss))`? Did you perhaps mix up b and c?

Comment: @davidlucius I have been trying to add another condition to your code which is some school may have a minimum grade in a specific subject , So even if there is a place for him in the school put he has a per example 9 in math and school only accept people who have more than 10 in math, so even if he could get to the school but because of his math grade he can't go now.
so we can add to your code two addition dictionary :
students_math_grade{
    'A': 12,
    'B': 15,
    'C': 07,
    'D': 18,
    'E': 05,
    'F': 11

}
min_grades{
    'DSI': 12,
    'RSS': 14,
    'CNM': 0
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem in your code could be that you are changing a list (`students_with_out_choice`) while iterating over it. This often leads to unexpected results.

As @enke has pointed out, the deferred acceptance algorithm is the method of choice here. An implementation of this algorithm could look something like this with your example:

```
s = {
    'A': ['CNM', 'DSI', 'RSS'],
    'B': ['CNM', 'DSI', 'RSS'],
    'C': ['DSI', 'CNM', 'RSS'],
    'D': ['DSI', 'RSS', 'CNM'],
    'E': ['RSS', 'DSI', 'CNM'],
    'F': ['RSS', 'CNM', 'DSI']
}

r = {
    'DSI': ['C', 'E', 'D', 'B', 'F', 'A'],
    'RSS': ['B', 'F', 'A', 'E', 'D', 'C'],
    'CNM': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
}

p = {
    'DSI': 2,
    'RSS': 2,
    'CNM': 1
}


def get_matched_students(students, rankings, places):

    waiting_students = [student for student in students]
    matching_results = {choice: [] for choice in places}

    def get_waiting_list_without_student(student):
        return [x for x in waiting_students if x != student]

    def get_sorted_results_with_student(student, choice):
        matching_results[choice].append(student)
        return [x for x in rankings[choice] if x in matching_results[choice]]

    while waiting_students:
        for student in waiting_students.copy():
            if not students[student]:
                waiting_students = get_waiting_list_without_student(student)
                continue
            choice = students[student].pop(0)
            if len(matching_results[choice]) < places[choice]:
                matching_results[choice] = get_sorted_results_with_student(student, choice)
                waiting_students = get_waiting_list_without_student(student)
            else:
                if rankings[choice].index(student) < rankings[choice].index(matching_results[choice][-1]):
                    matching_results[choice] = get_sorted_results_with_student(student, choice)
                    waiting_students = get_waiting_list_without_student(student)
                    waiting_students.append(matching_results[choice].pop())

    return matching_results


print(get_matched_students(s, r, p))
```

This will give you the lists of students that have been matched to each subject: `{'DSI': ['C', 'E'], 'RSS': ['B', 'F'], 'CNM': ['A']}`

If you want to see the results from the student's perspective, you can do something like this:

```
results = get_matched_students(s, r, p)

results_by_students = [[student, course] for student in s for course, result in results.items() if student in result]

print(results_by_students)

# Output: [['A', 'CNM'], ['B', 'RSS'], ['C', 'DSI'], ['E', 'DSI'], ['F', 'RSS']]
```

Comment: the output should be ((a,cnm),(c,rss),(b,dsi),(e,dsi),(f,rss))

Comment: @Abbad Med: Yes, because you changed the order of the input lists compared to your original question. ;) With the new input lists, my function also outputs the desired result: `{'DSI': ['B', 'E'], 'RSS': ['C', 'F'], 'CNM': ['A']}`.

Comment: @Abbad Med: I also just added a way to display the results from the student's perspective (like in your own solutions) in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually resolved my problem using two different solutions.

the first soltion is that found the bugs in my first program and i corrected it.

```
students = {
    'A': ['DSI', 'RSS', 'CNM'],
    'B': ['RSS', 'DSI', 'CNM'],
    'C': ['CNM', 'DSI', 'RSS'],
    'D': ['DSI', 'RSS', 'CNM'],
    'E': ['RSS', 'DSI', 'CNM'],
    'F': ['CNM', 'DSI', 'RSS']
}

choices = {
    'DSI': ['B', 'E', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'F'],
    'RSS': ['C', 'F', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'D'],
    'CNM': ['A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F']
}
rss = 2
cnm = 1
dsi = 2
nbr_of_speciality = 3
results = []
students_with_out_choice = []

for student in students:
    students_with_out_choice.append(student)

while len(students_with_out_choice) > 0:
    for student in students_with_out_choice:
        for i in range(nbr_of_speciality):
            choice = students[student][i]
            if (choice == "DSI" and dsi != 0) or (choice == "RSS" and rss != 0) or (choice == "CNM" and cnm != 0):
                results.append([student, choice])
                students_with_out_choice.remove(student)
                if choice == "DSI":
                    dsi -= 1
                if choice == "RSS":
                    rss -= 1
                if choice == "CNM":
                    cnm -= 1
                break

            else:
                free_choice = [k for (k,v) in results if choice == v]
                student_proposer = free_choice[0]
                for k in free_choice :
                    if choices[choice].index(k) > choices[choice].index(student_proposer):
                        student_proposer = k
                rating_of_propose_student = choices[choice].index(student_proposer)
                rating_of_actuel_student = choices[choice].index(student)

                if rating_of_propose_student > rating_of_actuel_student:
                    students_with_out_choice.remove(student)
                    results.remove([student_proposer, choice])
                    results.append([student, choice])
                    students_with_out_choice.append(student_proposer)
                    break
                elif i==nbr_of_speciality-1 :
                    print(f"student  non-oriented : {student}")
                    students_with_out_choice.remove(student)
                    break

print(results)
```

the seconde solution :

```
students = {
    'A': ['dsi', 'rss', 'cnm'],
    'B': ['rss', 'dsi', 'cnm'],
    'C': ['cnm', 'dsi', 'rss'],
    'D': ['dsi', 'rss', 'cnm'],
    'E': ['rss', 'dsi', 'cnm'],
    'F': ['cnm', 'dsi', 'rss'],
}
choices = {
    'dsi': ['B', 'E', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'F'],
    'cnm': ['A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'F'],
    'rss': ['C', 'F', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'D'],
}
places = {
    'cnm': 1,
    'rss': 2,
    'dsi': 2,
}

left_places = places
results = {}

students_with_out_choices = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
choices_left = students


def list_of_student_with_out_a_choice_left_to_prpose(students_with_out_choices, choices_left):
    results = []
    for e in students_with_out_choices:
        if len(choices_left[e]) > 0:
            results.append(e)

    return results


def last_choice_in_ranking(s, choices_left, results, choices):
    students_with_out_choices = []
    ranging_list = choices[choices_left[e][0]]
    ranging_student_list = []
    for key in results:
        if results[key] == choices_left[e][0]:
            students_with_out_choices.append(key)
    for i in range(len(ranging_list)):
        if ranging_list[i] in students_with_out_choices:
            ranging_student_list.append(ranging_list[i])
    if ranging_list.index(e) < ranging_list.index(ranging_student_list[-1]):
        return ranging_student_list[-1]
    return s

list_of_oriented_student = students_with_out_choices
while len(list_of_oriented_student) > 0:
    e = list_of_oriented_student[0]
    first_choice = choices_left[e][0]
    if places[first_choice] > 0:
        results[e] = first_choice
        left_places[first_choice] -= 1
        students_with_out_choices.remove(e)
    elif len(choices_left[e]) > 0:
        student_less_rank_than_e = last_choice_in_ranking(e, choices_left, results, choices)
        if student_less_rank_than_e != e:
            del results[student_less_rank_than_e]
            results[e] = first_choice
            students_with_out_choices.remove(e)
            students_with_out_choices.append(student_less_rank_than_e)
    choices_left[e].remove(choices_left[e][0])
    list_of_oriented_student = list_of_student_with_out_a_choice_left_to_prpose(students_with_out_choices, choices_left)
print("results: ", results)

liste_of_student_non_oriented=[]
for key in students:
    if key not in results:
        liste_of_student_non_oriented.append(key)

print(f"students non-oriented : {liste_of_student_non_oriented}")
```